# What's wrong with this C code? (Not working as expected)

Tags: c, function, pointers

I have another exercise for my C class. The code doesn't crash, but it doesn't work as expected. Obviously I've made a mistake I cannot find. 
The assignment goes like this:
The user inputs two characters c1 and c2 and an integer n and you have to create a function that creates dynamically and returns a string with n characters like this: c1c2c1c2c1c2 etc.
For example:
c1=a and c2=s and n=4 The string is: asas

However the array I created doesn't contain c1 and c2, but some random characters from the ASCII table. Plus here:

```
printf("\nThe string is: %s\n",s);
```

The output in the screen is like this: Ohe string is: I (Insted of The string is: s-whatever s is-)
Here's a link of a photo from the .exe file:

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* alternate(char c1,char c2,int n)
{
    int i;
    char *s;
    s=(char*)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(char));
    if(s==NULL)
    {
        puts("Could not allocate memory!");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++);
    {
        if(i%2==0)
            s[i]=c1;
        else
            s[i]=c2;
    }
    s[i]='\0';
    return s;
}

main()
{
    char c1,c2,*s;
    int n;
    puts("Give two characters: ");
    scanf("%c %c",&c1,&c2);
    fflush(stdin);
    puts("Give an integer: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    s=alternate(c1,c2,n);
    printf("\nThe string is: %s\n",s);
    free(s);
    system("pause");
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried running it in a debugger? Run it step-by-step to check that all works okay. Also you should check the return value of `scanf` to see that it succeeds.

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()` in a C program.  And `sizeof(char)` is `1`.

Comment: @CarlNorum Thanks for the tip! Our professor told as to do so (typecasting), in order the code to be compatible both with C and C++ compilers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the semi-colon next to your for loop statement:

```
 for(i=0;i<n;i++);
```

I removed the semi-colon & tried your code & it prints text as expected.

The semi-colon next to for loop makes it an empty loop and the statements which come after that are just some assignments which are scoped. That is,

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++);
    {
        if(i%2==0)
            s[i]=c1;
        else
            s[i]=c2;
    }
```

is same as

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++) 
{

}

{
   if(i%2==0)
      s[i]=c1;
   else
      s[i]=c2;
 }
```

Answer (score 6):

*Remove* the `;` at

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++);
{
```

it does not belong there.

Comment: I've made this mistake probably a thousand times last semester and I keep doing it! I've checked the code many times, but I didn't notice! Thanks!